# TS2322: Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'Store'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have a simple TypeScript Component where I try to implement type checking, but I cannot figure out what is wrong with the next part of code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Title } from '../components'
import { Props } from './types'

const AppContainer: React.SFC<Props> = ({ store }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Title />
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default AppContainer
```

Because I always gets an error:

> TS2322: Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'Store'.   Property 'dispatch' is missing in type '{}'.

Component Interface:

```
export interface Props {
  store: object,
  dispatch(): any,
  getState(): any,
  subscribe(): any,
  replaceReducer(): any
}
```

P.S.
I admit, that Type checking works fine if I remove bracers from the argument `store`, like:
`const AppContainer: React.SFC<Props> = (store) => ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

```
P.S. I admit, that Type checking works fine if I remove bracers from the argument store, like: const AppContainer: React.SFC<Props> = (store) => ...
```

Yes, this is exactly right! So the solution in your case is a very easy:

```
const AppContainer = ({ store }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Title />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

This is because you declare your function arguments like in destructive way. If you will choose the non-destructive `= (store) =>` you also can choose you own type-checking solution. It's not any different between both ways. You can choose one of them on you own.

Comment: Thank you! I already solve my problem with the second way. It work perfectly. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be capital O in object i.e. Object.

```
export interface Props {
  store: Object,
  dispatch(): any,
  getState(): any,
  subscribe(): any,
  replaceReducer(): any
}
```